# while loop android class not found

Tags: java, android, while-loop

So I am trying to create a simple loop in android but my varialbe is not recognized? Here is the problem code
package com.whatwouldayogido.iching3.app;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class rollHex {

    TrigramClass a = new TrigramClass();
    HexagramClass hex = new HexagramClass();
    String [] mHex = new String [2];
    String [] mChangingHex= new String [2];
  Random randC = new Random();
  int[] toss = new int [3];
  int changingTri = 0;
  int mTriCount = 0;

  while( mTriCount <= 1 ) {
      for (int i = 0; i <toss.length; i++){
         toss[i] = randC.nextInt(4)+6;
      }
      mHex[mTriCount]=(a.evaluateTrigram(toss));
      mChangingHex[mTriCount] = (a.evaluateTrigram(toss));

      if (a.checkChangingLines()){
        a.changingLines(toss);
        a.evaluateTrigram(toss);
        changingTri++;
        mChangingHex[mTriCount] = a.evaluateTrigram(toss);
      }
      mTriCount++;
  }

  if ( changingTri > 0) {
    //do stuff
  }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
Unknown Class mTriCount
```

My question is, am I donig something wrong here?  This program executes fine in java and this is the first time I have had such an error.  The loop seems fine.  What Am I missing?

Comment: Assuming this is a compile error, does it give line numbers?
Also, why is this question tagged c++ if it is an Android question?

Comment: Not sure why my tags got changed. I corrected them.  I'm using android studio, and I can't compile before I correct the errors.  The error is on the while-loop line.

Comment: @Zac: Well, to be fair, even though this looks like Java at first, you can use C++ with Android with the NDK...

Comment: Within this context, I am having a hard time seeing any issues.  would you mind posting the entire method or function?

@wiz3kid Thanks for the info, I did not know that... I've never used the NDK.

Comment: Edited to display the whole class. I'm quite baffled as I have never had this problem with java before.

Comment: you would've had your code in the `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your looping inside of a method.  Android will not let you get away with your current syntax.  You will need it to look more like:

```
public void foo() {
  while( mTriCount <= 1 ) {
    for (int i = 0; i <toss.length; i++){
       toss[i] = randC.nextInt(4)+6;
    }
    mHex[mTriCount]=(a.evaluateTrigram(toss));
    mChangingHex[mTriCount] = (a.evaluateTrigram(toss));

    if (a.checkChangingLines()){
      a.changingLines(toss);
      a.evaluateTrigram(toss);
      changingTri++;
      mChangingHex[mTriCount] = a.evaluateTrigram(toss);
    }
    mTriCount++;
  }

  if ( changingTri > 0) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Also, as good practice, you may want to add access modifiers to your class variables.

This should at least allow your program to compile.